# Azure Function as OAuth Service

Tags: azure, azure-functions

i've been tasked with researching and potentially the development of an azure function, dedicated to being and OAuth service. I haven't had much luck regarding the information on the subject, and i was wondering if this is even a viable option?

**EDIT:** I've found manny articles and resources showing how it's done with "Authentication as a Service" services, such as Azure AD B2C.

I don't want to use a service..

Comment: As in developing an oauth provider using azure functions?

Comment: @PramodValavala-MSFT exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I wouldn't recommend this, from an educational perspective, you would essentially have to implement the complete [RFC for OAuth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).

> **TL;DR** - If your intention isn't to write everything from scratch, you could always wrap some library like [oauth2-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oauth2-server) for example in a NodeJS function app.

This would include implementing an

1. [Authorization Endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.1)
2. [Token Endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.2)

And implement the various types of authorization flows like

1. Authorization Code Grant
2. Implicit Grant
3. Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant
4. Client Credentials Grant

Also, various other things like Revocation Lists, Client Registration, Roles, etc. and bunch of security best practices to protect your users.

Though a lot of work, it is possible and do note that you would also need some database along with functions.